# How do you disconnect a TV cable that runs all along the walls throughout the house?

Tags: cables

Is it dangerous to disconnect it by myself, or is the standard protective gloves and shears sufficient?

The cable was installed by Time Warner Cable company, and now we no longer have their service.

Comment: Can you elaborate on some details? Where are you disconnecting it from? What is the end goal?  Depending on what you want to achieve, you may want to leave the cabling itself for other TV service to user later.

Answer (score 1):

The co-ax TV cable in the house is considered "low voltage" and shouldn't pose a hazard to people (unless something is seriously wrong with the wiring, like it touching the mains somewhere).

First, I'd ensure that the cables in the house are disconnected from the cable service line. There should be a grounding block on the side of the house where the house's cable lines connect to the service lines. They may look something like:

[image: this Amazon product]

Disconnect the "house" side cable from the block, and then cut or tear out whatever cable you'd like. After this disconnection, the line should not be energized at all. As GrecMac commented, it is a good idea to use a non-contact voltage detector to ensure that the cables do not carry a dangerous voltage.

Comment: I'm pretty anal about using a non-contact voltage sensor whenever I work on mains wiring, but unless the house is full of questionable wiring (junctions not in boxes, extensions cords used as interconnects, missing grounds, etc) it's generally pretty safe to work with. Usual caveats apply: if you're concerned, check it with your sensor. Don't work with any wiring during a lightning storm. Use common sense.